# AWS Device farm insights for device usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I need to understand the fleet usage of our AWS device farm devices. Is there a way I can plot and understand the usage of these devices? Data which I am looking for:

- How many devices are being used are free at a given time?
- Which devices are used for how long?

I know AWS Device farm logs data to cloud Trail, and we can use that data to plot in cloudWatch - but is there not an automated way to understand the usage?